# Autosave form data after specific time

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, autosave

Is there any way to save form data after specific time?

I want a wordpress like post autosave feature. I have checked a few tutorials but they are related solving this with the help of AJAX and JavaScript (jQuery). I want to ignore ajax. Is it possible?

Comment: You have to do this with javascript, if you dont want to do it with Ajax, you will have to reload the page (ie submit the form) to save the data...

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do this without some form of JavaScript that reloads the DOM.

You could easily do this with jquery if you add something like this to your page.  Of course replace the data items with the items you have in your form and replace the 2000 with the period of time you want to use to autosave.

I use a laravel blade function, if you do this with raw php, just replace {{url(/your/post/route)}} with your url.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery.post("{{url(/your/post/route)}}", function (data) {
        jQuery("[name='name']").val(data.name);
        jQuery("[name='city']").val(data.city);
    }, "json");
    setInterval(function () {
        jQuery.post("{{url(/your/post/route)}}", $("form").serialize());
    }, 2000);
});
```